# Shopify Django App: printf: warning: ignoring excess arguments, starting with ‚;‘

Tags: python, django, shopify

Used python version: 3.7 and 3.8

I am trying to follow the official instruction from Shopify (in readme.md) to start a Django Shopify App:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_django_app

By step 2 in „Setup environment „, what look like that:

Generate a secret key and add it to .env by running the following in the command line: `printf 'DJANGO_SECRET=' >> .env; python -c 'import random; print("".join([random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)") for i in range(50)]))' >> .env`

I am getting a warning:

```
printf: warning: ignoring excess arguments, starting with ‚;‘
```

After running the command my .env file look like that:

```
SHOPIFY_API_KEY=“1111111111111111”
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET=“11111111111111”DJANGO_SECRET=
```

if course that generate me any key, what follow an error by trying to start a server on the next step from the instruction.

What I am doing wrong and why is not generating the key for me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think in your system `printf` is not invoking the builtin `printf` function. Try running the following command and it should generate random key for you.

```
/usr/bin/printf 'DJANGO_SECRET=' >> .env; python -c 'import random; print("".join([random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)") for i in range(50)]))' >> .env
```

Otherwise, you can generate a random id in shell or put any random string as a value of `DJANGO_SECRET` key in your `.env` file.
Finally, your `.env` file content will be:

`SHOPIFY_API_KEY=[your api key]
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET=[your api secret]
DJANGO_SECRET=[your_random_key]`

Now, try running the django server.